# Renew a web hosting certificate on IIS

Tags: tls, iis, web-hosting

I have a site published in IIS. The site using HTTPS protocol and the web hosting certificate is already expired. This web hosting certificate path is under the trust root certificate which is not expired yet. I am very new to this so I am not sure how to do since the certificate is created by the previous programmer. Can anyone help giving any idea on how to start?

Comment: This is not a security thing, but a server/web admin thing. Can you see who issued the TLS certificate? Can you just buy a new one? Getting a new certificate is one step. Installing it is another. All these things are easily looked up. Tech support from the original certificate issuer can also help.

Comment: And please do not cross-post on Stackexchange. You already have an answer on another site.